# AppWidget - list of elements without ListView

Tags: android, android-appwidget, remoteview

I'm working on an AppWidget that shows a list of elements from my db. I see that there are problems (compatibility mostly) with listview in appwidget, so I am looking for alternative solutions.

My idea was to have a series of TextViews in my layout (i.e. 10 TextView) and fill them from db (the first 10 elements in example). Is it a good solution? Moreover I need to change the visibility of TextViews to hide some of them if elements are less than TextView, but I didn't find how to change visibility of views in AppWidget, is it possibile?

Alternative idea is to add only TextView I need from code, but is this possible in TextView? How can I add TextView?

Thanks.

Comment: Ideally , You should create a ScrollView with one linear layout. Then Programatically Create a View using User Defined Adapter and add it to the ScrollView.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but also ScrollView is not supported from all versions and devices, is it right?

Comment: For App Widget not sure. But for Application Definitely Yes.You can refer the API docs there they mention from which platform it supported